How to receive email from Google Calendar invitations
How to receive an email whenever somebody invites me to a Google Calendar event?


Google Calendar > settings icon (gear) > "Settings"
On the left frame (middle), under "Settings for my calendars", click your calendar (the one whose event invitations should generate the email to you).
In the middle, under "Other notifications", you find "New events". Select "email".

If you can't select "email" and it says "automatic", you may wish first to do the following:

Google Calendar > gear icon (settings) > "Settings"
In the middle, under "Event settings", select:
"Add invitations to my calendar": "From everyone"

(My address is very public, yet no spammers have added anything to my calendar.)
Neither setting applies to invitations you have already received.
Note: you may wish to change also the settings below "New events", such as "Cancelled events".
